# Stick div to bottom right corner, but above footer at all time

Tags: css, html, positioning

I want a small div to stick to the bottom right corner of the browser. This I accomplished by doing this:

```
#div {
position: fixed;
bottom: 10px;
right: 10px;
}
```

But I've a footer, say height: 200px;. What I want is that when you scroll down the page the div stays in the bottom right corner, but when the footer pops up on the bottom of the page, I want the footer to push it upwards so it won't come in front of the footer.

I hope I made myself clear...

Comment: You'll need JavaScript for this.

Comment: Check this out http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/

Comment: It's been already asked on StackOverflow many times. I remember answering it once...

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while, but i think i got the answer for you :)

You should add JQuery to your HTML by adding this line, below the line where you add the css file:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then create a file scrollBottom.js (javascript file), and add that too like this:

```
<script src="scrollBottom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In that file you add the following code (edited: document.ready should be added):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()-200) {
           $('#div').css('bottom', $(window).scrollTop()-2360);
       }
        else
        {
            $('#div').css('bottom', '10px');
        }
    });​
});
```

working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/4VJtU/4/

Answer (score 1):

Love that this can be done without jscripting now. :) 
Just a few lines of CSS and some wrapper adjustments: 
http://jsfiddle.net/bitofgrace/QGEUv/

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="flyover">hi</div> <!-- the content you want to stick in the corner -->
<div class="content"> Body of page content</div>

<div ID="footer"> FOOTER CONTENT</div>
</div> <!-- close wrapper -->
```

The CSS

```
#wrapper {width:100%; height:100%; margin:0}
#flyover {background-color:pink; color:white; position:fixed; top: 87.5%; z-index:4;}
#footer {background:green; position:relative; height:100px; width:100%; bottom:0; z-index:1;}
```